# Android change the name of app which is to installed on homescreen

Tags: android, label, manifest

How to change the name of the app which is to be displayed on home screen?

Whenever I try to change the android:label="title_name" inside activity of manifest file, title bar changes which is expected. But app name also changes in home screen to "title_name"

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:label="title_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

Is there any other method to change app name only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android label tag is used for both **Default Title bar** and **App Name** in Home Screen

```
 android:label="@string/app_name"
```

If you want to change only App Name then change label and set **Title Bar Text** to your desire in onCreate() in your activity as below:

```
this.setTitle("Your Title");
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the android:label under the activity tag, which is causing this issue.

Your application name is **android:label="@string/app_name"**  under application tag, Go to the folder res/values/strings.xml where u can find something like this

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">APP NAME</string>
</resources>
```

mention your application name at "APP NAME". This will work

Answer (score 0):

You can change 'app name' in strings.xml

example)

`<string name="app_name">any</string>`

Comment: Yes, but whenever I change android:label="title_name", app name on home screen displays "title_name". Can you please tell me why does app name change?

Comment: 'android : label' is referenced with 'string/app_name'.

Comment: If you use title bar in you app, it could be another way to use "setTitle("example")"

Answer (score 0):

**android:name** attribute is for subclassing Application.

**android:label** attribute is for Application label(which is displaced on homescreen.)